# AngularJS execute validation on save click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a validation e.g. `ng-required`. Those validations are executed when user changes the value in input field.

But when I am creating new form and user clicks on save button validations are not executed, I need to check validation on save button click

Currently I am checking `Form.$dirty`.

Any ideas about the right way of handling validations in AngularJS?

Comment: You can look here , it may help https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in attribute `$valid` and use it in the `ng-submit`:

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate ng-submit="testForm.$valid && submit()">
```

The submit function is called only when `testForm.$valid` is true.

Comment: I need to have validation execute at each field when user click save